# key value pair array for specific email body in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have email body like this :

```
Title - Title Goes Here
Customer - Mr Abc Xyz
Terms And Conditions - You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any deals and 
offers.
You can refer our detailed information about this.
```

I have used `imap` to get email body like `['body']['html']` and i want to get key-value pair array, like this in `codeigniter3`

```
Array(
       [Title] => Title Goes Here,
       [Customer] => Mr Abc Xyz,
       [Terms And Conditions] => You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any 
                                 deals and offers.You can refer our detailed information about this.
     )
```

I have tried `explode()` to get above desired result.

```
$arr = explode("-", $emailBodyContent);
```

But It gives the following :

```
Array(
       [0] =>
       Title [1] => Title Goes Here,
       Customer [2] => Mr Abc Xyz,
       Terms And Conditions [3] => You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any 
                                 deals and offers.You can refer our detailed information about this.
     )
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are just splitting it by the `-`, you will not take into account the different lines of data.  The complicating part is the the last entry looks as though it may have multiple lines.

This code first splits it by new lines and then processes each line and splits it by the `-`.  If there are 2 parts - it adds them as a new item, if not (as in the last bit) it will just add the content to the last entry added...

```
$emailBody = 'Title - Title Goes Here
Customer - Mr Abc Xyz
Terms And Conditions - You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any deals and 
offers.
You can refer our detailed information about this.';

$lines = explode("<br>", $emailBody);  
$output = [];
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    $lineSplit = explode("-", $line, 2);
    if ( count($lineSplit) == 2 ) {
        $lastKey = trim($lineSplit[0]);
        $output [ $lastKey ] = trim($lineSplit[1]);
    }
    else    {
        $output [ $lastKey ] .= " ".trim($line);
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [Title] => Title Goes Here
    [Customer] => Mr Abc Xyz
    [Terms And Conditions] => You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any deals and offers. You can refer our detailed information about this.
)
```

Comment: `Message: Undefined variable: lastKey` is coming

Comment: `Array ( [0] =>
Title - Title Goes Here
Customer - Mr Abc Xyz
Terms And Conditions - You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any deals and offers. You can refer our detailed information about this.
[1] => )`    And count of lines give 2

Comment: As you suggested initially, i used "\n" only. I also tried with "\r\n" And variable `lastkey` scope is limited only to if condition so the above error throwing

Comment: Final output coming is `Array ( [
Title] => Title Goes Here
Customer - Mr Abc Xyz
Terms And Conditions - You must accept our terms and conditions before sign in for any deals and offers. You can refer our detailed information about this.
)`  . So its creating only one key

Comment: Yes it contains `<br>` after every lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203339/discussion-between-srk-and-nigel-ren).